# Make jQuery validator validate hidden inputs on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I have a button like

```
<button onclick="$('#myForm').submit()>Submit!</button>
```

which validates all inputs and submits if validated. I have one hidden input that I want validated as well. The inputs inside the form are all validated whenever their value changes, too. What I want to set the validator to validate hidden inputs.

All the examples I see on the internet are like

```
$("#myform").validate({
   ignore: ":hidden"
});
```

which **invokes the validation which is what I don't want**. I want to define what happens whenever it is invoked. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Wintermute that makes it not submit

Comment: You seem confused.  First, the `ignore` option tells it what NOT to validate.  So if you set `ignore: ":hidden"`, that is basically the default and hidden elements will NOT be validated.  Use `ignore: []` and nothing will be ignored; everything will be validated including hidden elements.

Comment: Secondly, when using jQuery, inline JavaScript handlers become obsolete.  Besides, you do not need an `onclick` handler inside the `button`... simply use the correct `type` attribute:  `<button type="submit">Submit!</button>`.